# dark mode option is not showing on emulator's setting

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-emulator, darkmode

[image]

dark mode option is not showing on emulator's setting

Comment: emulator device api? also try to pull statusBar, it might have

Comment: currently it is pixel 3a API 26 | android 8.0 , i have 8gb ram laptop so can you advice an emulator according to this please

Comment: try to use recent api while creating emulator device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the system wide dark theme is only available on `Android 10 (API level 29)` and above.

Since you are using an emulator with `Android 8 (API level 26)`, you will not be able to access the dark mode option in your settings.

To use this feature, you can either create a new emulator with minimum `Android 10 (API level 29)` or use a physical device that runs on at least `Android 10 (API level 29)`.

Comment: it won't affect a 8gb ram laptop na ?

Comment: Since  Pixel 3a API 26 is running on your system without any problems, new emulator will probably run too. Make sure that you have only one emulator running at a time.